exporting project with packed texture images
I'm having trouble exporting my model with textures using GLTF 2.0 in Blender. My model is a simple trading card layout with two JPG textures packed into the .blend file (verified in Shading view). However, the exported GLTF file is only around 10 KB, the images do not seem to be exporting. The images are jpg. I'm using a mixed shader and geometry with the textures plugged into the shader channesl. I've double-checked for missing files and ensured the images are packed. im using blender 4.1
